# HTTP file download progress bar in Go

Tags: http, go

I saw a post a while ago with a progress bar function using the `github.com/cheggaaa/pb` package along the lines of:

```
func download(destinationPath, downloadUrl string) error {
    tempDestinationPath := destinationPath + ".tmp"
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", downloadUrl, nil)
...
    var progressBar *pb.ProgressBar
    contentLength := strconv.Atoi(request.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
...
    io.MultiWriter(writer, progressBar)
...
```

I used it in some code, but I lost that code a few days ago and I cannot find this function anywhere again. If anyone could help me at least rewrite it, I'd be very grateful. It used io.Writer and io.MultiWriter to write the data both to a file and increment the progress bar at once. Thankk you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a similar package. https://github.com/schollz/progressbar

```
func download(destinationPath, downloadUrl string) error {
    tempDestinationPath := destinationPath + ".tmp"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", downloadUrl, nil)
    resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    f, _ := os.OpenFile(tempDestinationPath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    
    bar := progressbar.DefaultBytes(
       resp.ContentLength,
       "downloading",
    )
    io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(f, bar), resp.Body)
    os.Rename(tempDestinationPath, destinationPath)
    return nil
```

Answer (score -4):

there are a lot of other open source packages, try this one:
https://github.com/schollz/progressbar

example:
[image]